# Create a email listener using itemAdd c#

Tags: c#, email, outlook, listener

I'm using the itemAdd property of the mail to create the listener to alert whenever a new mail is in the mailbox. This is my piece of code

```
MAPIFolder inboxFolder = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items myItems = inboxFolder.Items;
myItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
        }

static void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
        {
            string filter = "Test";
           MailItem mail = (MailItem)Item;

            if (Item != null)
            {              
                if (mail.Subject.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("");
                    Console.WriteLine("Mail found");
                }
            }
        }
```

But it is not working.
Any fault in it?
Please suggest a solution 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you do some debugging? Does the event ever gets called?

Comment: That is my doubt.. Is the code good or does it need any changes?

Comment: Try changing the method from static to private.